# Cycle inside my app (building could produce unreliable results) on XCode 15.0.1 (15A507) and macOS Sonoma

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode15, macos-sonoma

After updating to Xcode 15.0.1 and macOS Sonoma (14.1), I am facing compile time issues with Xcode project. Earlier it was working fine on Xcode14

[image]

I cheked apple developer forum and other questions, an found that `order of target's build phases` is causing the issue. I reorder the build phases, but no luck. Below is the current order of build phases.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in error log. I checked log thoroughly and found cause of error (highlighed in red box below):

```
That command depends on command in script phase "Run Script"
```

[image]

I fixed the compile time error by changing the order of target's build phases as below. Now I am able to run app in simulator.
[image]